# How to convert a number to a date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime, numbers

I have a number, *"1546108200"*, in epoch format.

I want to convert into a date format, like *"Sunday, December 30, 2018 12:00:00 AM"*.

How can I do that?

Comment: `new Date(1546108200 * 1000)`

Comment: Where you're facing problem ?

Comment: "epoch format" = [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)?

Answer (score 35):

You can use this:

```js
var date = new Date(1546108200 * 1000);
console.log(date.toUTCString())
```

Comment: why do you need to multiply with 1000?

Comment: alert(moment(1546108200 * 1000).format("DD/MM/YYYY"));